# Calling Eventbrite API from .Net results in 401

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, eventbrite

I am trying to retrieve an order from the Eventbrite API. I have a valid OAuth token and order number. I have verified this by using postman which successfully returns the correct JSON.

However when I make the call using the following c# code, I get a 401 Unauthorised:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/orders/{orderNo}");
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer {authToken}");
var response = await client.SendAsync(req);
```

I've tried replacing the header with:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("{authToken}");
```

I have also tried:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/orders/{orderNo}");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer {authToken}");
request.Accept = "application/json";
using(WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
    using(Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                    {
                        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
}
```

All of these get a 401 response.
I know the authtoken and the eventid are correct, so there must be something wrong with my code.

Am I doing something wrong with the authroisation token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried ?token={authToken} option on the EventBrite API?

This would at least confirm if it's a problem with the way the header is being sent across.

http://developer.eventbrite.com/docs/auth/

Comment: Interesting, that putting the authToken in the querystring works. So as you said, this confirms there is something wrong with the way I have created the header. The header method works in postman, so it must be that I'm not creating it correctly in .net

Comment: I'd be tempted to fire up fiddler and see what is actually being sent in the request.  I've been caught out by the Expect header that .net adds under the covers so maybe there's something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You omitted the trailing '/' in the URL, which caused a subsequent redirect from "eventbriteapi.com/v3/orders/{orderNo}" to "eventbriteapi.com/v3/orders/{orderNo}/". The authorization header was dropped in the redirect.